# How to get rid of the yellow highlighted background in old search text in Qt Creator?

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I have searched for the string "as" a few hours before in Qt Creator.

However it seems to be still active and whenever I type "as" again it is highlighted automatically.

And I can't get rid of it.

It looks like this:

[image]

Do you know what could be the problem and how to remove the yellow highlight?

Comment: have you quit the search module ? Like, pressing escape a few times so that the tool bar disappear

Comment: do you use FakeVim ?

Comment: @Scab yes, I do. I have temporary fixed that by :noh but that four keystrokes and enter ;( . Do you know about something more elegant?

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment, you are using FakeVim so you can set whether or not search results are highligthed in Qt Creator ( Tools > Options > FakeVim). And if you want to clear the highlighted results, just type :nohlsearch in FakeVim.

Comment: :noh is enough, you don't need to type 7 additional letter. The highlighting is useful but I would prefer if it disappeared after I finish using search ;(

Answer (score 0):

If you are using FakeVim you can set up a user command in Tools -> Options -> FakeVim -> User Command Mapping. E.g., User command #1 = ":noh". Then you can use 'Alt+V 1' to get rid of the yellow highlight.